# Identity Server 3 with Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I currently have a solution with three projects

1. Identity Server 3 with web host
2. MVC Application with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
3. Asp.Net Web Form Application with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

Both the Mvc and WebForm are pointing to the same Identity Server and both are configured to use the same client. The Client is setup as a Hybrid flow and has both the MVC and Web Form urls registered against the client.

Both can authentication with the same user account details and the claims identity is working fine within the applications. Both are setup using the OpenID Connect Authentication with the same

1. Client ID
2. Authority URL
3. Response Type
4. Scopes
5. SigninAsAuthenicationType (Cookies)

Both the Mvc and Web Form are set up as UseCookieAuthenicationType (Cookies).

However when I transfer via a hyperlink from the WebForm application to the MVC application, it does not recognise that I am already logged in.

Can anyone tell me what I have configured wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide some code snippets from clients UseCookieAuthenicationType/UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication -configurations? Is Authority -property setted with valid endpoint? With security cookie it is case sensitive - this is important